# MAAS - UBUNTU 12.04.3 - ADD NODE BUT WITH ERROR

Tags: server, maas

yesterday I've installed a MAAS service on an Ubuntu 12.04.3 Lts Server Edition, the all installation was right the only error I received was when I added a node. The node has been added to MAAS but if I try to select it from UI see this error

;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached

someone can help me to resolve that?

thanks a lot

Comment: I don't know but I've resolved it just changed the name of each node by MAAS UI.

Comment: RiccardoMagrini: What was it before? Can you give an example of what the name was before and what it was after for a node? I think I might know what caused it depending on what you changed.

Comment: After I've added the node MAAS shows it with this name ;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a problem with my network, I've resolved that.